# How to calculate distance to nearest neighbor when new candidates are created over the years?

Tags: qgis, fme-form, time, nearest-neighbor

I want to calculate distances between sold properties and the nearest wind power turbine over the years 2013-2022, in FME. QGIS is also an option. I have coordinates for them both and also dates for when the properties were sold and dates for when the turbines were constructed. My challenge is to make the neighborfinder ignore turbines that were not built at the moment of sale. Do you have any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: In QGIS, you could use a combination of *Select by attribute* or *Extract by attribute* with *Shortest line between features* to filter out turbines by date before running the nearest analysis. I personally would do this in the graphical modeler.

Answer (score 4):

Few steps to this process, the first of them is running a Python Script, purpose of the script is to prompt the user to select the two layers containing the House data and Turbine Data.

Once that is done it will populate two new fields within the House layer containing the appropriate turbine ID and the Distance if there were no turbines built during the date you'll get a null value.

The last step is to run hub to spoke on the two layers.

**Project layout/attributes**
[image: Image of Project layout/attributes]

**Step 1; Create a new Python script and copy paste the following code**

```
"""
Created by ScoGer on 16/03/2023
Tested on QGIS 3.28.3

This script calculates the distance from each house point to the nearest turbine point
based on their respective dates. It adds two new fields to the house layer,
"nearest_turbine" and "distance", to store the nearest turbine ID and distance value.

The script uses a custom QDialog to allow the user to select appropriate house and turbine
layers as well as their corresponding date fields.
"""

from qgis.core import QgsProject, QgsFeatureRequest, QgsDistanceArea, edit, QgsField, QgsMapLayerProxyModel
from qgis.PyQt.QtWidgets import QDialog, QVBoxLayout, QLabel, QDialogButtonBox
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.gui import QgsMapLayerComboBox, QgsFieldComboBox
from datetime import datetime

class LayerFieldSelectionDialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        layout.addWidget(QLabel('Select House Layer:'))
        self.house_layer_combo = QgsMapLayerComboBox()
        self.house_layer_combo.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PointLayer)
        layout.addWidget(self.house_layer_combo)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel('Select House Layer Date Field:'))
        self.house_date_field_combo = QgsFieldComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.house_date_field_combo)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel('Select Turbine Layer:'))
        self.turbine_layer_combo = QgsMapLayerComboBox()
        self.turbine_layer_combo.setFilters(QgsMapLayerProxyModel.PointLayer)
        layout.addWidget(self.turbine_layer_combo)

        layout.addWidget(QLabel('Select Turbine Layer Date Field:'))
        self.turbine_date_field_combo = QgsFieldComboBox()
        layout.addWidget(self.turbine_date_field_combo)

        button_box = QDialogButtonBox(QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)
        button_box.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        button_box.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        layout.addWidget(button_box)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.house_layer_combo.layerChanged.connect(self.update_house_fields)
        self.turbine_layer_combo.layerChanged.connect(self.update_turbine_fields)

    def update_house_fields(self):
        self.house_date_field_combo.setLayer(self.house_layer_combo.currentLayer())

    def update_turbine_fields(self):
        self.turbine_date_field_combo.setLayer(self.turbine_layer_combo.currentLayer())

def calculate_distances(house_layer, house_date_field, turbine_layer, turbine_date_field):
    def nearest_turbine(house_feature, turbine_layer):
        min_distance = float('inf')
        nearest_turbine = None
        house_date = house_feature[house_date_field].toPyDate()

        for turbine_feature in turbine_layer.getFeatures():
            turbine_date = turbine_feature[turbine_date_field].toPyDate()
            if house_date > turbine_date:
                distance = house_feature.geometry().distance(turbine_feature.geometry())
                if distance < min_distance:
                    min_distance = distance
                    nearest_turbine = turbine_feature

        return nearest_turbine, min_distance

    with edit(house_layer):
        house_layer.addAttribute(QgsField('nearest_turbine', QVariant.String))
        house_layer.addAttribute(QgsField('distance', QVariant.Double))

        for house_feature in house_layer.getFeatures():
            nearest_turbine_feature, min_distance = nearest_turbine(house_feature, turbine_layer)
            if nearest_turbine_feature:
                house_feature['nearest_turbine'] = nearest_turbine_feature.id()
                house_feature['distance'] = min_distance
                house_layer.updateFeature(house_feature)

dialog = LayerFieldSelectionDialog()
result = dialog.exec_()

if result == QDialog.Accepted:
    house_layer = dialog.house_layer_combo.currentLayer()
    house_date_field = dialog.house_date_field_combo.currentField()
    turbine_layer = dialog.turbine_layer_combo.currentLayer()
    turbine_date_field = dialog.turbine_date_field_combo.currentField()

    calculate_distances(house_layer, house_date_field, turbine_layer, turbine_date_field)
```

**Step 2; Run the Python Script & Populate the Layer & Field Data**
[image: Image of Populating the Layer & Field Data]

**Outcome of Step 2**
[image: Image of Step 2 Outcome]

**Step 3; Run Join by Lines (Hub Lines) from Processing Tool Box**
[image: Image of Hub Lines]

**Final Overview with both Data/Visual Outputs**
[image: Image of Final Overview]

Answer (score 2):

That's an interesting problem to solve in FME. In short, the NeighborFinder won't do what you want by itself; there needs to be a little pre- or post-processing.

I can think of a few methods. The most likely is with lists and post-processing.

Here I'm using data I have available to find the nearest station to each library, and have made up a number to act the part of a date:

[image]

Since you can't exclude older turbines, what you do is have the NeighborFinder make a list of dates. So click the Generate List option and add the turbine ID and turbine Build Date attributes to that list:

[image]

Here's what I have now (edited the image to make it more readable):

[image]

The list is sorted in order of distance. So for Strathcona library ("date" = 3), the nearest station is Main St, but its date (2) is older. Then comes Stadium, but again with an older date (1). Then there is Waterfront, which is the answer because its date is newer (7).

*Notice the attributes are both called PretendDate. I realized here they needed different names, so future screenshots will have PretendDateLib and PretendDateStation.*

So, how to get that information automatically? Like this:

[image]

Basically, explode the list into separate entries, filter out station (turbine) dates older than the library (house), then keep only the closest one.

You'll notice that we started with 8 libraries and ended with 4. That's because 4 libraries had newer dates than ALL of the stations (that's what I get for using random numbers).

[I made the workspace available online here](https://github.com/FMEEvangelist/FMECommunity/raw/main/SupportFiles/NFDateGroups.fmwt). Remember, because it uses RandomNumberGenerators, you'll get different results each time (unless you cache the data and rerun from the RandomNumberGenerators onwards). I think it should show you enough to set it up for your own case.

This all works because FME keeps all of its features in order, and we're operating on that assumption. There is a solution that avoids making that assumption, but it's a little more complex, using a custom transformer with a loop.

Basically, you loop through each item in the list (using a ListIndexer) until you find one with a newer date. There's [a webinar video online](https://youtu.be/umQjpUgGSjE) that will help you if you want to go this way. But I think the above method should be absolutely fine, and possibly a little faster.

Comment: From creating this solution, I realized we were in need of a RandomDateGenerator transformer, for creating test data and the like. So I created one of those on the FME Hub! See: https://hub.safe.com/publishers/safe-lab/transformers/randomdategenerator#description